# Azure VM Role Problem

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

I have been accepected into the beta program for the VM Role.

In the email it says that i need to run a registery script to setup visual studio, i did this fine on my pc before i reinstalled it.

However when i go to link i was sent it doesnt work any more?

Does any one have the registery file or know the settings i need to change.

Thanks

Comment: beta program? is it still in betat? cannot be used in production?

Comment: Yeah its still in beta, however i dont think its going any where

Comment: no i ment i dont think microsoft is going to get rid of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll find the instructions in this blog post - http://blog.toddysm.com/2011/02/how-to-deploy-windows-azure-vm-role.html.

For convenience, here's the relevant section of the post:

**Please read the notification email carefully!** In the email you will find information how to enable VM Role features in the Visual Studio development environment. In essence you need to run one of the scripts below to add new registry key or just change the following [dword] registry key:

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010\1.0\VirtualMachineRoleEnabled​=1

[VM Role Features in VS2010 32-bit Registry Script](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=205313)

[VM Role Features in VS2010 64-bit Registry Script](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=206860)

The scripts above will enable the Add New Virtual Machine Role in the context menu in Visual Studio.

Comment: Best wishes on your VM Role endeavors. ;-)